# Image in div with opacity not working in Firefox

Tags: css

On the website I have a DIV with opacity 0.7 that slide down. Then another DIV with opacity 0 for holding the text ect. I also have a repeater with a image and the image is showing OK in IE, but not in Firefox and Chrome.
In IE the image is above the opacity, but behind in FF and Chrome.

CSS Slide down:

```
.panelThatSlides
{
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0.7);
}
```

Panel holding the text etc.:

```
.contentThatFades
{
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

CSS for the image is:

```
 style="background-color: #000000; z-index: 9999; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"
```

The site is here:
http://www.hkks.dk/nyside1/test.aspx

How do I fix the z-index for the image to work in FF and Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of that:

`background: RGBA(255, 255, 255, /* percentage opacity */);`

```
.panelThatSlides
{
    display: none;
    background: RGBA(1, 1, 1, 0.7);
    padding: 20px;
}

.contentThatFades
{
    background: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
    min-height: 600px;
}
```